# Remove Xib from superView when calling from extension Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have created view xib and calling it in extension of `ViewController`. My created Xib is simply displaying message and calling it on every `ViewController` if In case internet disconnects xib message appears.

Issue I am facing - How can I remove xib from superview? I am calling and display my xib but when I try to remove its not.

I need to `remove Xib on netcheck = true.`

Calling code in every ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  if netcheck == false {
     showNotificationView()
    }
 }
```

extension code:

```
extension UIViewController {
    
    func showNotificationView() {
        
        let viewW = offlineView.fromNib()
        view.addSubview(viewW)
        viewW.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        viewW.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        viewW.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        viewW.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,constant: -25),
        viewW.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        ])
       
    }
    

}
```

Comment: You say "when I try to remove its not".  How are you trying?

Comment: @PhillipMills  I m trying like this but I know its wrong `offlineView.removeFromSuperview(<#T##self: UIView##UIView#>)`  I am getting an idea what to pass in `self:UIView`

Comment: Two possibilities: Create the view only once as an instance variable so that your remove code knows what to pass OR give your view a `tag` and use that to locate it when you want it removed.  (See UIView docs for `tag` information.)

Comment: Thank you done it with view.tag thing.